# Qt QML Focus an Item (TextField) when showing a StackView Page

Tags: qt, focus, qml, stackview

I want to enable `TextField` focus when QML file is loaded. But, it is not working. After loading TestUi.qml file I put some button and its `onClick()` method I did `_recipientView.focus = true_`, it works fine. The problem is that default focus is not enabled when view is loaded first time.

TestUi.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0


Page {

    function init() {
        recipientView.focus = true;
    }

    TextField {
       id: recipientView
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        font.pixelSize: 18
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText | Qt.ImhEmailCharactersOnly
        focus: true
        placeholderText: "Email"
    
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
onComposeBtnClicked: {
    rootStackView.push(test)
    test.init()
}

TestUi {
    id: test
    visible: false
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set it via `Component.onCompleted: recipientView.focus = true;` ?

Comment: When app is starting to load, Component.onCompleted is running no matter  which page is. I did it no help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Edit

The `Page` component already acts as a `FocusScope`, so only forcing the active focus is necessary. Thanks for the comments.

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    initialItem: firstPage

    // Ensures the focus changes to your page whenever
    // you show a different page
    onCurrentItemChanged: {
        currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}

Page {
    id: firstPage
    visible: false

    TextField {
        // Explicitly set the focus where needed
        focus: true
    }
}
```

#### Original answer

This is simply because you are pushing `TestUi` into your stack with `rootStackView.push(test)`. When you do so, the focus is reset. This is typically handled with a [`QFocusScope`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-focusscope.html), which role is to remember the focused `Item`, and give the focus back to it when the `QFocusScope` regains focus.

In your case, adding a `QFocusScope` to your base page would enable restoring the focus correctly when the page is shown:

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    initialItem: firstPage
    onCurrentItemChanged: {
        currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}

Page {
    id: firstPage
    visible: false
    onFocusChanged: {
        scope.focus = true
    }
    FocusScope {
        id: scope
        TextField {
            focus: true
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use your page handler `onVisibleChanged` if you want to reset to focus when the user comes back to it (after a pop for instance), instead of memorizing it where the focus is. But in that case the `FocusScope` might be overkill.

For information, you can also use the `StackView` property `initialItem` in order to set the first page.

It is also kind of unrelated, but prefer `import`ing the most recent version of the QtQuick components available. QtQuick version will be 2.12 for Qt 5.12. A bit less trivial for [QtQtcuik.Controls version](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html#versions), but they are getting in line with that versioning scheme.

Comment: I have to set focus not to the main Page. For me worked just adding

    onCurrentItemChanged: {
        currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
    }
To main.qml. And adding Focus.scope to my target file caused an error.

Comment: For me adding onCurrentItemChanged was enough aswell. There are some QML items like Page that act as focus scopes themselves. (a list of those items can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-focus.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks. I don't remember if at the time, it was necessary, I will edit the answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The actual/non-trick way for Qt 5.8+ is using the `activated` attached signal as follows:

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    initialItem: firstPage
}

// As already mentioned by another answer, the Page acts like FocusScope
Page {
    id: firstPage
    visible: false
    
    // *** The Key! ***
    // Force to be active focus whenever this item is active. 
    // You need this on every loadable item with `FocusScope` behaviour.
    // So, it is a good idea to create a new component based on a `Page` 
    // that has the following signal handler
    StackView.onActivated: {
        forceActiveFocus()
    }

    TextField {
        id: txt1
        // Explicitly set the focus where needed
        focus: true
        // An example to show how you can control the focus chain
        KeyNavigation.tab: txt2
    }
    TextField {
        id: txt2
        // Previous focus item
        KeyNavigation.backtab: txt1
    }
}
```