# Switching pages using the keyboard and changing the focus

Tags: qt, qml

There are several pages in my program that display various information. I need to write code that will switch pages when I press the keyboard buttons. But I do not have a switch, although I wrote according to the examples given from the documentation. Switching works if there is a built-in Button on the page, that is, the problem is precisely in writing the Keys method

At first, I just checked switching pages in StackView - it works with built-in buttons, then I decided to connect the keyboard. The problem is added by the fact that I have each page defined in separate files. I determined that for Keys to work, it is necessary to set the focus (if there is a Button, the focus is placed on the button and everything worked correctly), but I most likely have some kind of mess with the focuses. Please tell me what I should fix. I'm at a loss right now.

Here are my files:

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ApplicationWindow {
    onActiveFocusItemChanged: print("activeFocusItem", activeFocusItem)
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("Robot")


    StackView {
            id: stack
            focus: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            initialItem:menu_page
        }
    FocusScope{
        id:scope
    }

    Item {
        id:page1
        Menu_page {
            id: menu_page
        }
        Connections{
            target:menu_page
            onButtonClicked:{
                stack.push(page2);
            }
        }
    }

    Item{
        id:page2
        visible: false
        Error_page {
            id: error_page
        }
        Connections{
            target:error_page
            onButtonMenuClicked:{
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Menu_page.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page{
    id:menu_page
    signal buttonClicked();
    signal buttonManualClicked();
    
    Item {
        id: win
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle{
            id: bot
            anchors.fill:parent
            color: "#373438"
        }
        
        ...   //Here is the page design
        
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Alt) {
            error_page.focus=true
            menu_page.buttonClicked();
            event.accepted= true
        }
        else if (event.key === Qt.Key_1) {
            menu_page.buttonManualClicked();
            event.accepted = true
        }
        else
        {event.accepted = false}

    }

    Item{
        id:page3
        visible: false

        Manual {
            id:manual_page
        }

        Connections{
            target:menu_page
            onButtonManualClicked:{
               stack.push(manual_page);
            }
        }

        Connections{
            target: manual_page
            onButtonFromManualToMenuClicked:{
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Error_page**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
//import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page {
    id: error_page
    signal buttonMenuClicked();
    width: 480
    height: 800

        ...   //Here is the page design
    

    //focus:stack
    Keys.onPressed: {                           //It doesn't work.
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Plus) {
            error_page.buttonMenuClicked();
            event.accepted = true

        }
        else
        {event.accepted = false}

    }

   Button{                            //I left the button to be able to return back to the page
        text:"Menu"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        onClicked: {
            error_page.buttonMenuClicked();
            //stack.pop()}
        }
    }
}
```

**Manual.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page {
    id:manual
    signal buttonFromManualToMenuClicked();

            ...   //Here is the page design

    Item{
        Keys.onPressed: {                                      //It doesn't work.
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Plus) {
                f4.color="#3d3131"
                //stack.pop()
                //error_page.buttonMenuClicked();
                manual.buttonFromManualToMenuClicked();
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
 
    Button{                         //I left the button to be able to return back to the page
        text:"Menu"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        onClicked: {
            manual.buttonFromManualToMenuClicked();
            //stack.push("Error.qml")
        }
    }
    
}
```

I don't have a transition from Error_page and Manual to Menu_page with Keys

In the process of switching Menu_page-> press Alt-> Error_page-> press Button-> Menu_page-> press 1-> Manual-> press Button-> Menu_page the focuses change in this order:

```
qml: activeFocusItem Menu_page_QMLTYPE_6(0x228d250)
qml: activeFocusItem Error_page_QMLTYPE_8(0x403ed30)
qml: activeFocusItem QQuickContentItem(0x3fdbb60, "ApplicationWindow")
qml: activeFocusItem Button_QMLTYPE_4(0x40663c0)
qml: activeFocusItem Menu_page_QMLTYPE_6(0x228d250)
qml: activeFocusItem Manual_QMLTYPE_5(0x40231e0)
qml: activeFocusItem Button_QMLTYPE_4(0x403e070)
qml: activeFocusItem Menu_page_QMLTYPE_6(0x228d250)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt QML Focus an Item (TextField) when showing a StackView Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299117/qt-qml-focus-an-item-textfield-when-showing-a-stackview-page)